# Sum and Echo Column Data from MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql

I am attempting to sum the data from a specific column in a MySQL database and then echo it to the page. My code is as follows:

```
<?php
//Trackingboard Display
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'disolDemo');
$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT sum(totLocMiles) FROM odoboard WHERE waybill_ID = '3'") or die($msqli->error);
$sumTot = mysql_fetch_array($query);
echo $sumTot[0];
?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is the output you get?

Comment: `echo "<pre>"; print_r($sumTot );` to check the output.

Comment: _"What am I doing wrong?"_ - you completely neglected to give us an actual problem description. Please go read [ask].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're mixing `mysqli` with `mysql`

try this

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'disolDemo');
$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT sum(totLocMiles) as sum FROM odoboard WHERE waybill_ID = '3'") or die($msqli->error);

 while($row = $query->fetch_assoc())
    {  
        echo $row['sum'];

    }
```

Comment: "fixing" -> mixing :-)